# Вот(,) [союзное слово]

Tags: запятые, частица, союзные-слова

Когда между частицей ВОТ и союзным словом ставится и когда не ставится запятая?

Comment: Не мешало бы конкретику иметь (эту частицу и союзное слово в естественной среде — примерах). Вы хотите трактата или ссылки?

Comment: Да, для тратата нужна конкретика,  а ссылку можно и самому найти в поисковике.

Comment: Сто раз уже спрашивали. Но это то, что стоит обсудить несколько раз.